# What is the difference between using apachectl and apache2 to restart Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I know of three ways to restart Apache:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

service apache2 restart
```

What does each way do underneath?

I have also tried using `service apache2 stop` on Ubuntu, but it doesn't stop the server for some reason: localhost still serves on my desktop.

Answer (score 10):

`service` and/or `init.d` scripts are exactly the same thing as it runs same `httpd` script, that was meant mainly to `stop` and `(re)start` `httpd` service, while `apachectl` can do more (see output).

`apachectl`:

```
# apachectl 
Usage: /usr/sbin/httpd [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                       [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                       [-k start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|stop]
                       [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-S]
Options:
  -D name            : define a name for use in <IfDefine name> directives
  -d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
  -f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
  -C "directive"     : process directive before reading config files
  -c "directive"     : process directive after reading config files
  -e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
  -E file            : log startup errors to file
  -v                 : show version number
  -V                 : show compile settings
  -h                 : list available command line options (this page)
  -l                 : list compiled in modules
  -L                 : list available configuration directives
  -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed settings (currently only vhost settings)
  -S                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
  -t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules 
  -M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
  -t                 : run syntax check for config files
#
```

Comment: ok reason im asking s because i used sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart and all my django static files now give 404 errors, thought it had something to do with the method of server reboot

Comment: @DrManhattan It's more likely that you had changed your configuration files (maybe with a rewrite). You did not notice it previously because the change did not take effect until you restarted the service.